# <!doctype ..../> for HTML5

Tags: html, css, doctype, html4

I have some HTML5 tags in my webpage. i have used `<!DOCTYPE html>` for the same webpage... But i'm facing some spacing issues. I have tried `line-height:0px; and vertical-align` also... But  by this some other issue opens up...so i can't use line-height:0;...

I have tried to change `<!DOCTYPE html>` to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

By this all issues have been fixed and working fine..:)...

I just want to know whether it is right way to add

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">"
```

in HTML5 page... It will work or not....or there is any other way for my HTML4 tags....

Thanks...

EDIT....

Here is some code.. kindly save it as html format then see...and also try with `"<!DOCTYPE html" only` ... you will find the difference...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">

.sharecon {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px 0 6px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;
}
.dvleft {
    float: left;
}
.mleft5 {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.text11 {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 11px;
}
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sharecon">
<span class="dvleft mleft5">
<input id="abc123" type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:EmailBoxGetFocus();CheckUncheck(this,'abc@gmail.com');SetSelectedCount();EmailBoxLostFocus();" value="abc@gmail.com" name="dlstContacts$ctl00$checkBoxSpn">
</span>
<span class="dvleft mleft15" style="margin-left:4px; margin:2px;">
<strong class="text11" style="line-height: 12px">ABC Name</strong>
<br>
<span class="light_text11" style="line-height:12px;display:inline"> abc@gmail.com </span>
</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please define *"some spacing issues"*

Comment: You would probably be better of posting the HTML that is causing the problems, then trying to fix it by using an older doctype.

Comment: `line-height:0px` is not a solution

Comment: can you share your code plz?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if changing the doctype like you described had any effect on spacing issues. Could you post the code you're working on somewhere so we can see?

Comment: added some code..kindly save it as html file...

Comment: Chrome 25, OSX – no difference whatsoever between two doctypes.

Comment: @Alochi ...I have already mentioned that i cant add "line-height:0px; and vertical-align" here...any other suggestions... and Oleg please see the same issue in Firefox.. you will find the difference there...:)

Comment: @Gaurav - It's not helpful to say that you can't do "action X" if you don't explain why not. "some other issue" is not an explanation.

Comment: Firefox 18, OSX – no difference whatsoever between the two doctypes...

Answer (score 1):

The XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype puts many browsers into [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html), which means an intentionally broken mode where the browser more or less emulates extinct versions of IE, with many bugs and oddities, or into [Almost Standards Mode](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), which is a less broken mode. Using `<!doctype html>` triggers Standards Mode, so if your page is disturbed by it, then it’s because your page relies on bugs that were once common in browsers.

It’s not easy to say what to do. If the page works with the XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype, it’s probably best to leave it that way, until the next full revision (rewrite) of the page. If this is a new page being created, it should be designed to work in Standards Mode from the beginning.

Note the use (or absence) of a doctype has nothing to do with support to HTML5 novelties. A browser does what it does with HTML5 features. The doctype is just a) a magic string that selects browser mode by complicated rules (affecting mostly how correctly CSS is applied) and b) a tool for specifying the syntax rules to be applied, if you use a markup validator.

Answer (score 0):

By adding this you are changing the doctype. See [link on Doc Types](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

You should look to change the relevant CSS/HTML if you are having styling issues within the actual page, you should create a new question including code if that is the case

Comment: [Typical w3schools](http://w3fools.com) I'm afraid. The one thing that really matters about the DOCTYPE, i.e. whether it causes quirks, almost standands or standards mode, is the one thing that page doesn't mention at all. For the OP's question is the difference in browser behaviour of almost standards mode (XHTML 1.0 Transitional) and standards mode (HTML5)